# conditions for the two functions have the same maximizer

Tags: calculus, optimization, quadratics

I have two quadratic functions $$W(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i}^{n} a_{ii} x_i^2+ \sum_{i\neq j}^{n} a_{ij}x_ix_j+\sum_{i}^{n} b_{i} x_i, $$  and $$V(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i}^{n} c_{ii} x_i^2+ \sum_{i\neq j}^{n} c_{ij}x_ix_j+\sum_{i}^{n} d_{i} x_i,$$with $x_i\in[0,1)$. Both functions are subject to constraint $\sum_{i}x_i \leq M$ where $M<n$. All parameters $a_{ii}, a_{ij}$, $b_{ii}$, $b_{ij}$ and $d_i$, $b_{i}$ to be non-negative. Note I split the second order terms, they can be written into one term like $\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n} a_{ij}x_ix_j$.

My question is, when will the two functions have the same maximizer? A sufficient condition is when the parameters are all same: $a_{ij}=c_{ij}$, $b_i=d_i$, for all $i,j$. Or parameters of $V$ is proportional to parameters of $W$. See [Why coefficients have to be proportional for two quadratic functions to have the same roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646322/why-coefficients-have-to-be-proportional-for-two-quadratic-functions-to-have-the). But is this necessary? Other than special cases where they are multiples of each other, can I have a simple necessary and sufficient condition? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if $a_{i,i}<0$, $c_{i,i}<0$, and $b_i=d_i=0$ for all $i$, as well as $a_{i,j}=c_{i,j}=0$ for all $i,j$ with $i\neq j$, then the maximizer of $W$ and $V$ is the same: $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n=0$.  You will see that $W$ and $V$ are not proportional in most choices of $a_{i,i}$'s and $c_{i,i}$'s.

Comment: @Batominovski, thanks for commenting. I already restricted all parameters to be non-negative.

Comment: If the parameters are nonnegative, there shouldn't be a maximizer.  $W$ and $V$ are increasing in each $x_i$.  If the domain were to be $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ for all $i$, then in most cases, there will be a unique maximizer $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n=1$.  If you want to discuss the minimizer, then in most cases, the minimizer will be unique: $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n=0$.

Comment: @Batominovski, you are right, I over-simplified the set-up. $x_i$'s should have a constraint.

Comment: Anyhow, the maximizer must lie on the $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane $\sum_{i=1}^n\,x_i=M$.  In most cases, there are no maximizing points, unless you allow the $x_i$'s to be $1$.  In that case, in most cases, there exists a unique maximizing point at which $\lfloor M\rfloor$ of the $x_i$'s must be $1$, whereas at least $n-1-\lfloor M\rfloor$ of them are $0$.

Comment: For a fixed $M$ with $0\leq M\leq n$, the unique maximizing point is $\big(1,1,\ldots,1,M-\lfloor M\rfloor,0,0,\ldots,0\big)$, for example, when $\left(a_{i,i}\right)_{i=1}^n$ and $\left(c_{i,i}\right)_{i=1}^n$ are strictly decreasing, $a_{i,j}=c_{i,j}=0$ for all $i,j$ with $i\neq j$, and $b_i=d_i=0$ for all $i$.  I'm not sure if there is a sensible characterization you are asking for.